# Single PHP Loop to print the no. sequence in Ascending or Desending

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have two variable
x and y

if x = 5 and y = 10     I would like to print

```
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and if x = 10 and y = 5 then I would like to print

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
```

I have wrote this code in 2 Loop using IF

Is there any logic to print this using a single Loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a lot simpler than other answers:

```
foreach (range($x, $y) as $number) {
    echo $number . "<BR>";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: Yes I agree, that's better :)

Comment: +1, range is the best suited solution for this question

Comment: -1. This creates an array in memory with all the possible values in the range. Try something like `foreach (range(1, 10000000) as $number) /*do nothing*/ ;` and it will exhaust the usual 128M limit.

Comment: Removed the -1. You have a point here. But I will not remove my comment as I think it can be valuable for other people reaching this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
$increment = ($x < $y) ? 1 : -1;

for ($i = $x; $i != $y; $i += $increment) {
    echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $x = 10;
    $y = 5;

    for ($i = 0; $i <= abs($x-$y); $i++) {
        if ($x > $y)
            echo $x-$i . "<br />";

        elseif($x < $y)
            echo $x+$i . "<br />";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you're looking for this:

```
<?php

$x = 5;
$y = 10;

while ($x != $y) { // this loop prints the numbers until they are equal
    if ($x < $y) echo $x++ . "\n\n"; // if x < y print and increment x
    else echo $x-- . "\n\n"; // else print and decrement x
}

echo $x . "\n\n"; // now the two nos are equal, print the no itself
```

Answer (score 0):

One cycle, one condition for each iteration

```
<?php

$x = 5;
$y = 10;

$start = $x;
$step = $x < $y ? 1 : -1;
$stop = $y + $step;

for ($i = $start; $i != $stop; $i+=$step) {
    echo $i . "\n";
}
```